# React: background image won't show

Tags: reactjs

I'm new at React.

I'm trying to show some images from an array. But I can't figure out what is wrong or what I'm doing wrong here...

Heres my code:

```
function Product(props) {
  const content = props.products.map((product) =>
    <article key={product.id} className="item-lg-3 item-md-6 item-sm-6 item-xs-12">
                    <div className="product-item">
                        <div className="product-item_img" style={productImg} data-product-image={product.img}>
                            <div className="product-item_img__view">
                                <button className="button button_g" data-toggle="#modal">View details</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <header className="product-item_header" data-product-name={product.header}>{product.header}</header>
                        <div className="product-item_desc">{product.desc}</div>
                        <footer className="product-item_footer">{product.price}</footer>
                    </div>
    </article>
  );
  return (
    <div className="flex-row">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

const products = [
  {id: 1, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Hello World', desc: 'Welcome to learning React!', price: "$ 999.00"},
  {id: 2, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Installation', desc: 'You can install React from npm.', price: "$ 699.00"}
];

const productImg = {
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + products.img +')'
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Product products={products} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: While you run this code, is there any js error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, products is an array, to access the img you need to specify the index also, like this:

```
const productImg = {
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + products[index].img +')'
};
```

You are passing the products array in component, so instead of using it like, define the `backgroundImage` in the component itself. Try this:

```js
function Product(props) {
  const content = props.products.map((product) =>
    <article key={product.id} className="item-lg-3 item-md-6 item-sm-6 item-xs-12">
      <div className="product-item">
          <div className="product-item_img" style={{background: 'url('+ product.img + ') 50% 10% no-repeat', height: '200px', width: '200px'}} data-product-image={product.img}>
              <div className="product-item_img__view">
                  <button className="button button_g" data-toggle="#modal">View details</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <header className="product-item_header" data-product-name={product.header}>{product.header}</header>
          <div className="product-item_desc">{product.desc}</div>
          <footer className="product-item_footer">{product.price}</footer>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
  return (
    <div className="flex-row">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

const products = [
  {id: 1, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Hello World', desc: 'Welcome to learning React!', price: "$ 999.00"},
  {id: 2, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Installation', desc: 'You can install React from npm.', price: "$ 699.00"}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Product products={products} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: I see, but I also have to show the image through the data attribute: data-product-img={product.img}, it only says (Unknown) when I inspect the DOM... Why?

Comment: check the working code, and i checked the `dom`, `data-product-img` contains the image `url` , run the above snippet and check the dom again :)

Comment: Oh, I see now what I did wrong... I spelled the data-product-image wrong. Thank you! It works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something as follows would do:

```
function Product(props) {
  const content = props.products.map((product) =>
    <article key={product.id} className="item-lg-3 item-md-6 item-sm-6 item-xs-12">
      <div className="product-item">
        <div className="product-item_img" style={getProductImageStyle(product)} data-product-image={product.img}>
        <div className="product-item_img__view">
          <button className="button button_g" data-toggle="#modal">View details</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <header className="product-item_header" data-product-name={product.header}>
        {product.header}
      </header>
      <div className="product-item_desc">{product.desc}</div>
      <footer className="product-item_footer">{product.price}</footer>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
  return (
    <div className="flex-row">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

const products = [
  {id: 1, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Hello World', desc: 'Welcome to learning React!', price: "$ 999.00"},
  {id: 2, img: 'https://cdn.stayhard.com/storage/ma/469381f40f20434bb5ab0eadce937803/5f53203dfc9b4d94b68880d3af79ab25/3200-3872-0-jpg.Jpeg/F51A68C2AE2FC6A99C4D52BEE2F66FBA650BFAF2/04247543_display.jpeg', header: 'Installation', desc: 'You can install React from npm.', price: "$ 699.00"}
];

const getProductImageStyle = product => ({
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + product.img +')'
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Product products={products} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I wrote this from top of my head, so not sure whether it works by just copy paste.

Anyways, try and let us know.

Comment: Yes! That works fine. But my other problem, as you can see I use data-procut-image={product.img}... That one still don't work. Can you see why? @gor181

Comment: I guess you have some sort of listener attached to data-product-image? Whats the purpose of data-product-image?

Comment: Yes. I send the image to a modal/pop up... And it wont show. I tried this before without an array and it worked out, but now when I have an array it don't

Comment: Thats pretty weird. I would compare the html for both approaches. Also it could be that script which initializes the event handlers for modals is trying to register them before react renders thus its not working as listeners weren't bound